# Transparent Toolbar is Gray

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-styles

What am I doing wrong? My min api level is 21. I'm trying to make the toolbar transparent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <!-- Content -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the style:

```
<!-- Toolbar transparent -->
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar.Transparent" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

And this is the result:

[image: Transaparent toolbar results gray]

Answer (score 0):

you have put framelayout below the toolbar in relative layout.
refer the code below will solve your problem.

```java
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar.Transparent"
        or
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <!-- Content -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```